# PyAudio don't search portaudio.h (macOS 12.2.1)

Tags: python, pyaudio, portaudio

I install pyaudio but it doesn't find portaudio.h
The path is:

```
    brew install portaudio
    brew link portaudio 
Warning: Already linked: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/19.7.0

     pip install --global-option='build_ext' --global-option='-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/' --global-option='-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/' pyaudio
```

Where is mistake?

Comment: Should it perhaps be `-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/include/` for the first option?